# Requirejs - error when trying to use firebase scripts

Tags: firebase, requirejs

I am working on a login page, using firebase for user authentication.

This is the main.js script

```
require.config({
    paths: {
        'firebase': '/scripts/lib/firebase-app',
        'firebase-auth': '/scripts/lib/firebase-auth',
        'firebase-database': '/scripts/lib/firebase-database'
    },
    shim: {
        'firebase-auth': ['firebase'],
        'firebase-database': ['firebase']
    }
});
```

I have this in a firebase-init.js

```
define(['firebase'], function(firebase) {
    var config = {
        apiKey: "...",
        authDomain: "...",
        databaseURL: "...",
        projectId: "...",
        storageBucket: "...",
        messagingSenderId: "..."
    };
    firebase.initializeApp(config);
});
```

This is login.js

```
define(['firebase', 'firebase-auth', 'firebase-init'], 
       function(firebase, firebaseAuth, firebaseInit) {
    ...
    code to login/logout user
    ...
});
```

When I run it, I get this error.

```
  TypeError
    columnNumber: 31509
    ​fileName: "http://localhost:3000/scripts/lib/firebase-auth.js"
    ​lineNumber: 1
    ​message: "n is undefined"
    ​stack: "Zn@http://localhost:3000/scripts/lib/firebase-auth.js:1:31509\nbi@http://localhost:3000/scripts/lib/firebase-auth.js:1:33789\n@http://localhost:3000/scripts/lib/firebase-auth.js:1:69619\n@http://localhost:3000/scripts/lib/firebase-auth.js:1:186\n@http://localhost:3000/scripts/lib/firebase-auth.js:1:2\n"
```

And this one.

```
Error: Cannot instantiate firebase-auth - be sure to load firebase-app.js first.
```

This is my first time using Requirejs. Do I have any configuration wrong? In the network tab, I can see firebase-app.js is being loaded before firebase-auth.js.

Thanks.

PS: It works fine if I use firebase.js, instead of using firebase-app.js and firebase-auth.js separately.

Comment: I think this lib in incompatible with RequireJS. Tried to run this code many times and I failed :<

Answer (score 0):

you must call firebase.app.js like "@firebase/app"

see my answer here [Error loading firebase js with requirejs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51765525/error-loading-firebase-js-with-requirejs/54025334#54025334)

Answer (score -1):

I think you need to amend your `firebase-init.js` module to load all firebase modules first, as they need to be loaded before calling the `firebase.initializeApp`.

```
define(['firebase', 'firebase-auth', 'firebase-database'], function(firebase) {
    var config = {
        apiKey: "...",
        authDomain: "...",
        databaseURL: "...",
        projectId: "...",
        storageBucket: "...",
        messagingSenderId: "..."
    };
    firebase.initializeApp(config);
});
```

Also you should consider adding `exports` to the shim.

Please confirm whether this is working :)

Comment: No, loading all the firebase modules to firebase-init.js did not change the error.

Comment: @DamianDziaduch Were you able to figure it out?

Comment: @Mr.Dev no, I didn't