# Error loading firebase js with requirejs

Tags: javascript, firebase, requirejs

I load Firebase js library with RequireJS like this:

```
require([
    'firebase-app',
    'firebase-storage'
], function (firebase) {
    firebase.initializeApp({...});
    firebase.storage();
});
```

Until Firebase js release 4.12.1 everything was ok, since 4.13.0 release I get these errors on "firebase.storage()" call:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'registerService' of undefined
>       at firebase (index.esm.js:3442)
>       at index.esm.js:3434

and

> Uncaught Error: Cannot instantiate firebase-storage - be sure to load firebase-app.js first.
>       at firebase (index.esm.js:3444)
>       at index.esm.js:3434

In Firebase 4.13.0 release notes there is this the change I think is breaking my code:
https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/js#version_4130_april_19_2018

> [CHANGED] Refactored to use core-js for our Polyfills/Shims.

"core-js" is this library: https://github.com/zloirock/core-js

These are the jsfiddle examples:

- library 4.12.1 - https://jsfiddle.net/ptmw0srq/27/ (the old and working one)
- library 4.13.0 - https://jsfiddle.net/ptmw0srq/28/
- library 5.4.0 - https://jsfiddle.net/ptmw0srq/30/
- loading only the full js works again - https://jsfiddle.net/ptmw0srq/72/

Comment: added jsfiddle examples

Comment: If I remember well, RequireJS does not guarantee a specific load order, so if your assumption is true, you need to find a way to _really_ load app before storage. If I am right, in your case this solution (or a flavour of it) would be appropriate: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16362754/3744574.

Comment: It's not a order issue, following your suggestion I get another error: "Uncaught Error: Mismatched anonymous define() module: ..."

see new example https://jsfiddle.net/ptmw0srq/34/

Comment: added working version with full firebase js library, but It forces to download a lot of unused scripts

Comment: Seems like the 4.12.1 to 4.13.0 jump was a significant refactor. The way app.js is being defined has changed, which is probably what breaks it. It is interesting that the 5.4.0 storage appears to work fine with the 4.12.1 app still, suggesting it's a problem in the app itself, particularly in what storage imports and what app exports. The firebase object appears to get lost in the process. A dirty workaround if you can't switch to an npm or similar system is loading firebase first and assigning it to the global scope. Don't know the side-effects though: https://jsfiddle.net/ptmw0srq/85/ :[

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution at this page (valid only for firebase release >= 5.5.6):

https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/issues/1266#issuecomment-441405513

you must call firebase.app.js like "@firebase/app", so:

```
var config = {
    paths: {
        '@firebase/app': 'https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/5.7.1/firebase-app',
        '@firebase/storage': 'https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/5.7.1/firebase-storage'
    }
};
require([
    '@firebase/app',
    '@firebase/storage'
], function (firebase) {
    firebase.initializeApp({
        ...
    });

    firebase.storage();
});
```

final jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ptmw0srq/125/