# How to use Firebase Database and Firebase Storage with Require.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, requirejs

I want to use Firebase-Database and Firebase-Storage with Require.js.

I have my file structure set up like this:

```
../
   js/
      app.js
   lib/
      require.js
   app/
      main.js
      firebase_refs.js
```

My app.js config file:

```
requirejs.config({
"baseUrl": "js/lib",
"paths": {

  "app": "../app",
  "firebase_refs": "../app/firebase_refs",
  "jquery": "//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min",

  "firebase": "//www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/5.5.6/firebase-app",
  "firebase-auth": "//www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/5.5.6/firebase-auth",
  "firebase-database": "//www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/5.5.6/firebase-database",
  "firebase-storage": "//www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/5.5.6/firebase-storage",

 },

 "shim": {
    "firebase": {
        exports: "firebase"
    },
    "firebase-database": {
        exports: "firebase-database"
    },
    "firebase-storage": {
        exports: "firebase-storage"
    }
}
});

requirejs(["app/main"]);
```

My main.js file (which I use to initialize Firebase):

```
define(['firebase'], function (firebase) {

var FirebaseAppInit = {
    setupFirebase: function(){

        var config = {
            apiKey: "xxx",
            authDomain: "xxx",
            databaseURL: "xxx",
            storageBucket: "xxx",
        };

        firebase.initializeApp(config);
    }
};

return FirebaseAppInit;
});
```

My firebase_refs.js file (which I use to declare the firebase database root reference and the storage reference):

```
requirejs(["app/main"]);

define(['firebase-database', 'firebase-storage'], function(FirebaseDatabase, FirebaseStorage){

var Refs = {
    rootRef: function(){
        return FirebaseDatabase.database().ref();
    },
    storage: function(){
        return FirebaseStorage.storage();
    }
};

return Refs;

});
```

And, now finally in my index.html file:

```
<script>

    var test_header = document.getElementById("test_header");

    require(['app/main'], function(firebase){

        firebase.setupFirebase();

        require(['app/firebase_refs'], function(FirebaseRefs){

                var dbRef = FirebaseRefs.rootRef().child('some kind of text');
                dbRef.on('value', snap => test_header.innerText = snap.val());
            });

    });

</script>
```

### The issue I'm having

The error I get is:

```
Error: Script error for "@firebase/app", needed by: firebase-database, firebase-storage
https://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#scripterror
```

I understand that there is an issue with the order in which I'm loading the firebase-database and firebase-storage, but I don't see where. Any suggestions?

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51765525/error-loading-firebase-js-with-requirejs/54025334#54025334

Answer (score 0):

you should use another path:

```
...
"paths": {
  ...
  "@firebase/app": "//www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/5.5.6/firebase-app",
  "@firebase/auth": "//www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/5.5.6/firebase-auth",
  "@firebase/database": "//www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/5.5.6/firebase-database",
  "@firebase/storage": "//www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/5.5.6/firebase-storage",

 },
...
```

and then use it in your main.js file

```
define(['@firebase/app'], function (firebase) {
    console.log(firebase);
}
```